# Java: getRowForLocation() returns different row int when Jtree has expanded nodes or collapsed nodes

Tags: java, jtree, dom4j

`JTree jtree` has a mouse listener attached to it.when the user clicks on a Jtree component node, I get it's row integer via

```
 jtree.getRowForLocation(evt.getX(), evt.getY());
```

the problem is that the return row integer is different when there are jtree nodes which are expanded and when it's collapsed.

I need a way to somehow get a unique and absolute ID of each jtree nodes clicked so that there is no confusions.

Is there a way to add data to the Jtree component?

Otherwise, I need a way to listen to when nodes are expanded and recalculate the row returned from that above function....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current approach you are relying on the state of the tree view to identify the node. However, as you have found out the state of the view can change. What does not change is the tree model that is underlying the view.

If you need a unique ID for each node then you should add this directly to each tree node in your tree model. In the mouse listener you can then detect the node that you clicked on and access its unique ID.

Comment: how can I directly add a unique ID directly to each tree node? The tree node itself is generated from an xml file which the treemodel is generated from. This treemodel is then rendered into Jtree.

Comment: Can you add unique IDs to the source XML file? Or after the tree model is created can you walk it and set unique IDs on each node?

Comment: I have added unique ID to the source xml file. do you mean add a model listener to the tree model?

Comment: One final question is, is it possible to convert the tree model into xml file?

Answer (score 1):

Paths uniquely identify nodes, so `getPathForLocation` will give you the path, but that is a `TreePath` object, so if you have to have an integer represent the ID you would need to write a method that translates `TreePath`s to integers.

Comment: do you mean take the tree path and create a unique ID from that?

Comment: Yes, if you really need integer IDs.
But since you get direct access to the elements of the tree with `TreePath.getLastPathComponent()`, you might not need to use IDs, depending on what you want to do with the nodes.

Comment: I used `findComponentAt(x,y)` to find the component....what is the unique ID? do you mean the flags property of the jtree node componenent?

Comment: A hashcode is not guaranteed to be unique -- it's just designed to be very unlikely to be the same for different objects.
The safe solution is to go through the tree and assign a number to each element (either by editing the components or by using some helper datastructure like a map).